# Oracle SQL: Excluding a record from query results only when TWO conditions are met

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a pretty large Oracle SQL query. I want to add the following logic to my where clause, described in pseudocode below. Is it possible? I want to exclude a record if and only if BOTH columnA and columnB are null. If one or the other is null, that's okay.

```
    IF (pfr.columnA && pfr.columnB != NULL)
        exclude record
    ELSE
        do nothing
```

I tried the below except from my where clause, but obviously it does not accomplish what I need.

```
AND (pfr.columnA IS NOT NULL AND pfr.columnB IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: what kind of data types are A and B?

Comment: What you posted should work, post your entire query.

Comment: No, the psuedocode above is not clear, hence the wrong query result. When building a result set, the logic is to include records, so you want to include them. So you need to reverse the psuedocode, apply the else condition AS the condition. Apply NOT to the condition you state, and as user1161318 states below, this is either `NOT (pfr.columnA is NULL and pfr.columnB is NULL)` or `(pfr.columnA is not NULL or pfr.columnB is not NULL)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
where NOT (pfr.columnA is NULL and pfr.columnB is NULL);
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `ColA IS NOT NULL AND ColB IS NOT NULL`

Comment: No it isn't. As per DeMorgan's laws, it is not, and you can try it yourself in SQLFiddle.  This does what the OP wants.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding the OP's logic.  assume colA and colB are both true NOT true yields false.  Assume colA and colB are both false NOT false yields true.  Assume either colA is null OR colB is null result is true NOT true is false.  Now take a look at ColA is not null AND colB is not null.  Same assumptions, if colA is null AND colB is null the expression is true.  If colA is true and colB is true result is true. If colA is false and colB is false result is false since false AND false is false...

Comment: A simpler way to look at it is in how NOT distributes.  NOT (x AND y) = (NOT x) OR (NOT y).  In addition to reversing the values, it also reverses the operation.

Comment: I think OP explanation was a bit of, he either needs an AND or an OR sample data with expected results would of made this a no brainer.

Comment: Good point.  Well, for anyone interested, here's the link to my fiddle, which presents the problem and solution as I understand it.  Maybe the OP can take a look and try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dfa5/2

Comment: @JonH - When you apply the not operator to the statement, it applies to all boolean conditions, including the AND. It would be equivalent to ( ColA IS NOT NULL OR ColB IS NOT NULL )

Comment: Exactly.  Which is different from colA is NOT NULL AND colB is NOT NULL.

Comment: @REW Understood my point was the op could of posted sample data and expected results and this problem would of been solved in seconds.

Comment: I completely agree with you.  Although admittedly, I enjoyed this comment thread since I got to quote DeMorgan's laws.  What can I say, I'm a nerd!

Comment: @user1161318 in this case you could of gotten away with ColA is not null OR colb IS NOT NULL

Comment: Yes, that would work too.  It comes down to preference.  the NOT (x AND y) is more compact, but it's just as accurate to phrase it your way.

Comment: -1: I'm pretty sure this syntax (WHERE NOT..)is not permissible,except with EXISTS or IN, but am happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: You are wrong. Where not () is acceptable. Not is a boolean operator applied to whatever boolean operation follows. Here that is the result in the ().

Comment: ok, -1 reversed: I tried the sql fiddle link above and it does seem ok for oracle. I stand corrected!

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE 
case when pfr.ColumnA is null then 0 else 1 end + 
case when pfr.columnB is null then 0 else 1 end > 0
```

or

```
where (pfr.columnA is not null or pfr.columnb is not null)
```